# I cannot connect to youtube

Tags: browser, youtube

i can connect to all other websites, only youtube website is always down for me.

1. I tried all browsers on my desktop computer (DELL XPS 8500) (IE ("This page can’t be displayed"), Chrome("This webpage is not available"), Firefox("The connection has timed out"), all latest versions)
2. I tried clear browser cache, browsing history, doesn't work
3. I'm living in Canada and my ISP doesn't block youtube
4. My all other devices, ipad, ipod touch, samsung galaxy S3 all can connect to youtube.
5. I tried with other PCs on the same home WIFI network, and all of them can connect to youtube. Only my PC is not connecting.
6. Scanned for virus or malware, nothing found.

I'm not using any proxies.

OS system: windows 8.1

This problem is very annoying and i haven't been on youtube for half a year...

Comment: Scan for maleware?

Comment: Sounds like your ISP is blocking the website.  You would need to get a VPN or proxy to get around the block.  I assume you live in a region where this behavior is normal.

Comment: I'm living in Canada and my ISP doesn't block youtube.

Comment: anti-virus? some web content stuff with your av?

Comment: Is it possible someone has edited the host file, by pointing www.youtube.com to 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into cases like this in the past and have been using Hitman Pro & MalwareBytes. Seems to clean things right up.

The other possibility like NIM suggested is someone might have manually edited the HOSTS file. Here is a link show you how to edit that: [Windows 8.1 Hosts File EDIT](http://www.sysprobs.com/how-to-edit-host-file-in-windows-8-1-8)

Since you said you can connect to all other websites AND other devices on your network can connect to youtube then logically it has got to be malware/virus or some indirection in the hosts file.

Comment: does it mean normally the hosts file should be empty apart from some # comments, right?

Comment: Usually the only entry you will see in there is: '127.0.0.1       localhost' but it can be empty.